# VB.NET FlowControlPanel scrolling automatically when it shouldn't

Tags: vb.net, flowlayoutpanel

Very strange issue in VB.NET.  I have a simple WinForm that has a FlowControlPanel that takes up the entire form except for a status bar at the bottom.  If I add enough items to my panel so that a vertical scrollbar is needed, then scroll to the bottom, anytime I update my status bar the panel automatically scrolls back to the top.  Anyone ever see this?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: The first control in the panel probably has the focus, and the panel is trying to bring it into view.

Comment: Good call!  That's exactly what it was.  Didn't realize the FlowControlPanel automatically sets focus to the 1st control.  Fixed it putting code in the scroll event to move the focus to a visible control and all is now good.  Thank you!